# Form submit is not sending any POST data

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, post

On my web page, when I press the "Add Customer" link, the following happens:

- the onclick handler is called, which

  - sets values into the forms two text fields
  - displays an alert (at this point you can see the new values in the text fields on the screen)
  - calls the form's submit button (Note: the form submits back to it's own PHP file)
- The same php file is called, but there are no POST values received

  - I've verified this with

    - the code in the first line that counts the values in $_POST then displays later
    - using fiddler to look at the request sent to the page

I've done this type of thing numerous times before with no problems. I've copied this code to two different web servers (linux, apache) with the same result. It's probably a minor problem but I can't find it.

I've stripped out a whole bunch of code to get down to this little bit, but haven't figured out why no POST values are being sent.

You can see a working copy of this at http://www.daleann.org/dla.php. The only thing need besides the code below is /js/jquery.min.js.

Thanks for your help.

```
<?php
$pc=count($_POST)."<br />".date("H:i:s");
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("inside docReady");
  $(document).on('click', "a.menuBillingOwner", function() {
    $("#selectedBillingOwner").val("11");
    $("#lastCustomNavSelected").val("selectedBillingOwner");
    alert("selectedBillingOwner = "+document.forms['formBillingOwner'].elements['selectedBillingOwner'].value);
    document.forms['formBillingOwner'].submit();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="menuBillingOwner">
    <li><a href='#' id='menuBillingOwnerAdd' class='menuBillingOwner'>Add Customer</a></li>
  </ul>
  <?php
  $lastCustomNavSelected = $selectedBillingOwner = "";
  if (count($_POST) > 0 && isset($_POST['selectedBillingOwner'])) {
     $lastCustomNavSelected = "selectedBillingOwner";
     $selectedBillingOwner = $_POST['selectedBillingOwner'];
  }
  ?>
  <?php echo "pc = ".$pc."<br />\n"; ?>
  <form name="formBillingOwner" id="formBillingOwner" method="POST" action="/dla.php">
    <input type="text" id="lastCustomNavSelected" value="<?php echo      $lastCustomNavSelected; ?>" />
    <input type="text" id="selectedBillingOwner" value="<?php echo $selectedBillingOwner; ?>" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're already using jQuery, why `document.forms['formBillingOwner'].elements['selectedBillingOwner'].value` instead of `$('#selectedBillingOwner').val()`?

Comment: I added that because I was stumped and want to be sure that the fields were actually set and thought maybe my jquery wasn't right.

Answer (score 11):

Simple, because your form fields don't have `name` attributes, see below

```
<form name="formBillingOwner" id="formBillingOwner" method="POST" action="/dla.php">
    <input type="text" id="lastCustomNavSelected" value="<?php echo      $lastCustomNavSelected; ?>" />
    <input type="text" id="selectedBillingOwner" value="<?php echo $selectedBillingOwner; ?>" />
  </form>
```

Add names to them, for example:

```
<form name="formBillingOwner" id="formBillingOwner" method="POST" action="/dla.php">
    <input type="text" id="lastCustomNavSelected" name="lastCustomNavSelected" value="<?php echo      $lastCustomNavSelected; ?>" />
    <input type="text" id="selectedBillingOwner" name="selectedBillingOwner" value="<?php echo $selectedBillingOwner; ?>" />
  </form>
```

**Note:** Probably your jQuery assignments need to be fixed too but if that was the only issue then atleast a wrong value should have been `POST`ed to PHP, hence that is not ***the*** issue.

Comment: Thank you!! I figured it would something minor and stupid. Now don't I feel silly!! I'd be more embarrassed if I told you how long I've been doing web pages. After reading your answer, I thought to myself "I don't always include the 'name' attribute", but they are there in other pages that I've looked at.

Comment: Cheers, happens to all of us

Answer (score -3):

Delete these 2 lines of your jQuery.

```
$("#selectedBillingOwner").val("11");
$("#lastCustomNavSelected").val("selectedBillingOwner");
```

because that will change the value of textfield before your submit the form

Comment: "Don't add sugar into your coffee, it will become sweet if you do it." Well duh, I wouldn't be doing it if I didn't want it sweet. :P