# Form not sending any data when submitting form : $_POST is empty

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm trying to submit a simple form with video files in it, a title and a description. My code works on my laptop that has a 8.1.9 php version and not working on my desktop that has 8.1.0 php version.

I checked this page : [Form submit is not sending any POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040138/form-submit-is-not-sending-any-post-data) but I didn't find any solutions.

I checked php.ini but everything was set normaly... I checked for overlappings tags but didn't find any...

I hope that this is not to obvious...:/

Here is my code :

**add-videos.php**

```
<?php

require_once './partials/header.php';
include_once './fetch-videos.php';

?>


<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_is_admin'])) : ?>
    <button id="myBtn">Ajouter une vidéo</button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <form action="add-videos-logic.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <label for="video">Fichier vidéo</label>
                <input type="file" name="video" /> <br><br>
                <label for="title">Titre de la vidéo</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" /> <br><br>
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <input type="text" name="description" /> <br><br>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="envoyer">

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

<?php endif ?>

<?php while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
    
    <h2> <?= $fetch['title'] ?> </h2>
    <p><?= $fetch['description'] ?></p>
    <video width="320" height="240" cont rols>
        <source src="<?= $fetch['source'] ?>" data-id="<?= $fetch['id'] ?>">
    </video>
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_is_admin'])) : ?>
        <button><a href="delete-video.php?video_id=<?= $fetch['id'] ?>&source=<?= $fetch['source'] ?>">Supprimer</button>
        <button type="submit" name="update" value="modifier"> </button>
    <?php endif ?>

<?php } ?>


<?php

require_once './partials/footer.php';

?>
```

**add-videos-logic.php**

```
<?php
require './config/database.php';


date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');

var_dump($_POST);
var_dump(isset($_POST["submit"]));


if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    extract($post);
    
    $file_name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
    $file_temp = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['video']['size'];

    if ($file_size < 50000000) {
        $file = explode('.', $file_name);
        $end = end($file);
        $allowed_ext = array('avi', 'flv', 'wmv', 'mov', 'mp4');
        if (in_array($end, $allowed_ext)) {
            $name = date("Ymd") . time();
            $location = 'video/' . $name . "." . $end;
            if (move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $location)) {
                mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `videos` VALUES('', '$name', '$location', '$description', '$title')");
                header('location: ' . ROOT_URL . '/admin/add-videos.php');
            }
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Wrong video format')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('File too large to upload')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be related to different upload_max_filesize and post_max_size settings on the two installations?

Comment: Your SQL and file uploading is insecure but not your current issue. What does developer console show, is POST being submitted and are values there?

Comment: `extract($post);` That is a security nightmare that PHP used to do but has long since removed! Not good for you to be reintroducing the error

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: `add-videos.php`  appears to be processing a query execution that does not seem to have happened! i.e. no connection made no `execute()` or `query()` Just a `while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query))`

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` show you?

Comment: var_dump($_POST) is empty. Thank you for all this advices, I know that this not fully optimal but I'm learning and there is a lot of failures, i was going to improve security step by steps. $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query) is in ./fetch-videos.php. It seems that my form is not submitted.

Answer (score -2):

file size configuration to modify in php.ini post_max_size was too small.
Sorry for this question.
Adios stackoverflow